# Absolute transparent window

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make a window to when calling `window.Show()`, it would be absolutely topmost and would not take over control at the time of appearance.

Now so:

1. In appearance, it sometimes falls under other client applications and you have to return it using Alt+Tab
2. During the appearance takes control

   ```
   ResizeMode= "NoResize"
   WindowStyle= "None"
   AllowsTransparency= "True"
   WindowState= " Maximized"
   Topmost= "True"
   ```

The purpose of the window, without interfering, show notifications.

Comment: re "absolutely topmost": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253